# phonegap sqlite integration to store data inside application for building ios app via phone gap

Tags: database, sqlite, cordova

I am beginner to phonegap. I need  to add sqlite to my app to store some data.

Does anyone have clear sample app or step by step tutorial?

Comment: Your question is way too broad and its impossible to provide a single correct answer making it unfit for the Stackoverflow format. Try googling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Phonegap uses databases like `localStorage, indexedDB, webSQL`

If you want to use SQLite then you will need some kind of SQLite wrapper or you can say plugin.

You can check this wrapper https://github.com/brodysoft/Cordova-SQLitePlugin

There is some examples included in the documentation of that plugin. e.g.

```
// Wait for Cordova to load
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

// Cordova is ready
function onDeviceReady() {
  var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: "my.db"});
}
```

See the documentation to learn more.

Comment: thanks alot let me try